# How to get the position/index of a Sheet object in Java Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, xssf

In a Java method, I am using an Apache POI Sheet (from `XSSFWorkbook`). I can read the sheet name using `getSheetName()` method. But is there any way to find the sheet position in the workbook? I don't see any methods like `getSheetIndex()` in the [Sheet interface](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not in `Sheet` interface but `Workbook` has one method to do that :

```
Workbook.getSheetIndex(String name);
```

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that but was looking for something inside Sheet :-) else I have to call the parent workbook and then pass sheet name to it. Not very straight forward. But I guess no other way then.

Comment: @takias There's no need! Just use [Sheet.getWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getWorkbook())!

Comment: It will look like `Sheet.getWorkbook.getSheetIndex(sheet.getSheetName())`